# Having Trouble With Functions in C#

Tags: c#, function

I was working on a program that tries to calculate the absolute value of a given number. There's a few parts to my code. The first part checks to see if the equation is one or two terms, by monitoring a numeric up down box. If it's one term, only one input box will appear, and a public variable called p.choice is set to 1. However, If it's two terms, two input boxes will appear, p.choice is set to 2. When the user clicks the go button, the program checks if p.choice is equal to 1 or 2 (i'll add an exception for 0 later). I don't have a function for 2 yet. But if p.choice is equal to 1, it runs a function called calculate1(). This function checks, based on a public variable that it picks up from the first text box, whether or not that variable is positive or negative. If it's negative, it makes it positive. Then it returns that variable. Here is my code of the entire class (nothing is called from another class)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int calculate1()
    {

        Form1 p = new Form1();
        if (p.box1 < 0)
        {
            p.box1 = p.box1 * -1;
        }
        return p.box1;
    }
    public int choice;
    public int box1;
    public int box2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 p = new Form1();
        decimal changeValue = numericUpDown1.Value;
        changeValue = Convert.ToInt32(changeValue);
        if (changeValue == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            p.choice = 1;
        }
        else if (changeValue == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            p.choice = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            p.choice = 0;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 p = new Form1();
        if (p.choice == 1)
        {
            //p.box1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            //p.box1 = calculate1();
            //string result = "The Answer Is " + p.box1;
            //label2.Text = "5";
            //MessageBox.Show("Answer!", result, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            label2.Text = "Hello World";

        }
        else if (p.choice == 2)
        {
            p.box1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            p.box2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem comes on the button click. Nothing happens, which I know means that p.choice is not being set equal to anything, because I don't have an else clause yet. However, I can't seem to figure out why p.choice isn't being set to 1, when I select 1 on the number box, and put in a value. In an earlier edit, I tried to set label2.text = to a conversion of the p.choice into an int32. And when I changed the box number, the label changed correctly with the box number. So I know that the number is registering during this part of the code. I just can't figure out why it's not working in the next part. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Something wrong with `Math.Abs` ?

Comment: In every method that you reference `p.choice` you can simply reference `choice` which is a property of the form and therefore in scope for the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.choice` is always zero, because you keep instantiating a new `Form1` object in each function.

This line:

```
Form1 p = new Form1();
```

calls the constructor of the `Form1` class, which sets the field `choice` (an `int`) to its default value of zero.

Thus when you check the value of `p.choice` in your conditional logic, neither the `if` or `else if` are true:

```
// This is false, because p.choice is zero
if (p.choice == 1)

// This is false, because p.choice is zero
else if (p.choice == 2)
```

You do not need to create a new instance of the class, because you are already in it.

Remove this line:

```
Form1 p = new Form1();
```

Instead use `this`, which is reference to the class instance, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.choice == 1)
    {
        //this.box1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        //this.box1 = calculate1();
        //string result = "The Answer Is " + this.box1;
        //label2.Text = "5";
        //MessageBox.Show("Answer!", result, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        label2.Text = "Hello World";

    }
    else if (this.choice == 2)
    {
        this.box1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        this.box2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    }
}
```